# FatalThrowableError Call to undefined function App\Console\Commands\getCNofDNn()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to ask for help I am trying to edit ldapsync file. Because I need to synchronize manager attribute. The problem is that attribute is in dn format. I have function to explode only cn from dn and than make select id from mysql with that username as condition. My problem is when I run ldap sync it look like works for a while but than show. Please help me.

FatalThrowableError Call to undefined function App\Console\Commands\getCNofDNn()

```
    <?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\Setting;
use App\Models\Ldap;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Location;
use Log;

class LdapSync extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'snipeit:ldap-sync {--location=} {--location_id=} {--summary} {--json_summary}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command line LDAP sync';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */ 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes
        ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');

        $ldap_result_username = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_username_field;
        $ldap_result_last_name = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_lname_field;
        $ldap_result_first_name = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_fname_field;
        $ldap_result_active_flag = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_active_flag_field;
        $ldap_result_emp_num = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_emp_num;
        $ldap_result_email = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_email;
        $ldap_result_mobile = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_mobile;
        $ldap_result_manager = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_manager;
        $ldap_result_title = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_title;
        $ldap_result_cost_center = Setting::getSettings()->ldap_cost_center;

        try {
            $ldapconn = Ldap::connectToLdap();
            Ldap::bindAdminToLdap($ldapconn);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($this->option('json_summary')) {
                $json_summary = [ "error" => true, "error_message" => $e->getMessage(), "summary" => [] ];
                $this->info(json_encode($json_summary));
            }
            LOG::error($e);
            return [];
        }

        $summary = array();

        $results = Ldap::findLdapUsers();

        // Retrieve locations with a mapped OU, and sort them from the shallowest to deepest OU (see #3993)
        $ldap_ou_locations = Location::where('ldap_ou', '!=', '')->get()->toArray();
        $ldap_ou_lengths = array();

        foreach ($ldap_ou_locations as $location) {
            $ldap_ou_lengths[] = strlen($location["ldap_ou"]);
        }

        array_multisort($ldap_ou_lengths, SORT_ASC, $ldap_ou_locations);

        if (sizeof($ldap_ou_locations) > 0) {
            LOG::debug('Some locations have special OUs set. Locations will be automatically set for users in those OUs.');
        }

        // Inject location information fields
        for ($i = 0; $i < $results["count"]; $i++) {
            $results[$i]["ldap_location_override"] = false;
            $results[$i]["location_id"] = 0;
        }

        if ($this->option('location')!='') {
            $location = Location::where('name', '=', $this->option('location'))->first();
            LOG::debug('Location name '.$this->option('location').' passed');
            LOG::debug('Importing to '.$location->name.' ('.$location->id.')');
        } elseif ($this->option('location_id')!='') {
            $location = Location::where('id', '=', $this->option('location_id'))->first();
            LOG::debug('Location ID '.$this->option('location_id').' passed');
            LOG::debug('Importing to '.$location->name.' ('.$location->id.')');
        } else {
            $location = NULL;
        }

        if (!isset($location)) {
            LOG::debug('That location is invalid or a location was not provided, so no location will be assigned by default.');
        }

        // Grab subsets based on location-specific DNs, and overwrite location for these users.
        foreach ($ldap_ou_locations as $ldap_loc) {
            $location_users = Ldap::findLdapUsers($ldap_loc["ldap_ou"]);
            $usernames = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $location_users["count"]; $i++) {
                $location_users[$i]["ldap_location_override"] = true;
                $location_users[$i]["location_id"] = $ldap_loc["id"];
                $usernames[] = $location_users[$i][$ldap_result_username][0];
            }

            // Delete located users from the general group.
            foreach ($results as $key => $generic_entry) {
                if (in_array($generic_entry[$ldap_result_username][0], $usernames)) {
                    unset($results[$key]);
                }
            }

            $global_count = $results['count'];
            $results = array_merge($location_users, $results);
            $results['count'] = $global_count;
        }

        $tmp_pass = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
        $pass = bcrypt($tmp_pass);


        for ($i = 0; $i < $results["count"]; $i++) {
            if (empty($ldap_result_active_flag) || $results[$i][$ldap_result_active_flag][0] == "TRUE") {

                $item = array();
                $item["username"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_username][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_username][0] : "";
                $item["employee_number"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_emp_num][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_emp_num][0] : "";
                $item["lastname"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_last_name][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_last_name][0] : "";
                $item["firstname"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_first_name][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_first_name][0] : "";
                $item["email"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_email][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_email][0] : "" ;
                $item["mobile"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_mobile][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_mobile][0] : "" ;
                $item["manager"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_manager][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_manager][0] : "" ;
                $item["title"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_title][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_title][0] : "" ;
                $item["cost_center"] = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_cost_center][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_cost_center][0] : "" ;
                $item["ldap_location_override"] = isset($results[$i]["ldap_location_override"]) ? $results[$i]["ldap_location_override"]:"";
                $item["location_id"] = isset($results[$i]["location_id"]) ? $results[$i]["location_id"]:"";

                            function getCNofDN($dn) {
                            $return=preg_match('/[^cn=]([^,]*)/i',$dn,$dn);

                            if ($dn != "") { 

                            return($dn[0]);

                            }
                            return null;

                        } 

                if ( array_key_exists('useraccountcontrol', $results[$i]) ) {
                    $enabled_accounts = [
                        '512', '544', '66048', '66080', '262656', '262688', '328192', '328224'
                    ];
                    $item['activated'] = ( in_array($results[$i]['useraccountcontrol'][0], $enabled_accounts) ) ? 1 : 0;
                } else {
                    $item['activated'] = 0;
                }
        // insert
        include "connn.php";


$dn = isset($results[$i][$ldap_result_manager][0]) ? $results[$i][$ldap_result_manager][0] : "" ;

$managername = getCNofDNn($dn);

if ( $managername != "")    {   

mysqli_query($connn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$managername';";

$result = mysqli_query($connn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $manager_idd = "$row[id] ";

    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results getCNofDN('$dn'); $managername";
}
mysqli_close($connn);

} else {
    $manager_idd = "0";


}
                // User exists
                $item["createorupdate"] = 'updated';
                if (!$user = User::where('username', $item["username"])->first()) {
                    $user = new User;
                    $user->password = $pass;
                    $item["createorupdate"] = 'created';
                }

                // Create the user if they don't exist.
                $user->first_name = e($item["firstname"]);
                $user->last_name = e($item["lastname"]);
                $user->username = e($item["username"]);
                $user->email = e($item["email"]);
                $user->employee_num = e($item["employee_number"]);
                $user->activated = $item['activated'];
                $user->phone = e($item['mobile']);
                $user->manager_id = $manager_idd;
                $user->jobtitle = e($item['title']);
                $user->cost_center = e($item['cost_center']);

                if ($item['ldap_location_override'] == true) {
                    $user->location_id = $item['location_id'];
                } else if ($location) {
                    $user->location_id = e($location->id);
                }

                //$user->notes = 'Imported from LDAP';
                $user->ldap_import = 1;

                $errors = '';

                if ($user->save()) {
                    $item["note"] = $item["createorupdate"];
                    $item["status"]='success';
                } else {
                    foreach ($user->getErrors()->getMessages() as $key => $err) {
                        $errors .= $err[0];
                    }
                    $item["note"] = $errors;
                    $item["status"]='error';
                }

                array_push($summary, $item);
            }

        }

        if ($this->option('summary')) {
            for ($x = 0; $x < count($summary); $x++) {
                if ($summary[$x]['status']=='error') {
                    $this->error('ERROR: '.$summary[$x]['firstname'].' '.$summary[$x]['lastname'].' (username:  '.$summary[$x]['username'].' was not imported: '.$summary[$x]['note']);
                } else {
                    $this->info('User '.$summary[$x]['firstname'].' '.$summary[$x]['lastname'].' (username:  '.$summary[$x]['username'].' was '.strtoupper($summary[$x]['createorupdate']).'.');
                }
            }
        } else if ($this->option('json_summary')) {
            $json_summary = [ "error" => false, "error_message" => "", "summary" => $summary ];
            $this->info(json_encode($json_summary));
        } else {
            return $summary;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please propose a smaller code that produce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the function getCNofDN inside an if and a for loop. If the code doesn't run, your function doesn't exists.

Declare the function als private method and call it.

Comment: Thanks for reply could you please tell me how to declare as private because i am not sure if I declared it right.

Comment: declare it with `private function bla() {}` in the class an not in the method. You should learn the basics about OOP

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not have `getCNofDNn()`  method inside of `LdapSync` class. Create one first so you can access it.

Then use `$this->getCNofDNn($dn);` instead of `getCNofDNn($dn)`.

**OR**

If you inherit this method, **use** `$this->getCNofDNn($dn);`.